# insserv: Script is broken

Tags: networking

I am following this link

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=234588

for setting up my WOL settings.This is my script

﻿cat wakeonlanconfig

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
#!/bin/bash
ethtool -s enp3s0 wol g
exit
### END INIT INFO
```

But I got this

```
update-rc.d -f wakeonlanconfig defaults
insserv: Script wakeonlanconfig is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script wakeonlanconfig is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script wakeonlanconfig is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
```

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For information about init.d skeleton please check [this Q/A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18802/how-to-correctly-add-a-custom-daemon-to-init-d) in Ubuntu SE site

You need to implement such header in your init script:

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Sample_GT02 daemon startup script
# Description:       Sample Server for GT02 class 
### END INIT INFO
```

Answer (score 1):

Your tutorial is a little old :)

Now your startup script should have a header, something like this :

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          scriptname
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.
### END INIT INFO
```

See https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts for more informations