# Make a program start on booting

Tags: boot, yocto

I have a c++ program which I want it to run at booting time on a yocto distribution.

I tried adding a simply script on /etc/init.d/ called test.sh in which I just have:

```
echo "start my program"
ProgramName
```

with "ProgramName", my program runs when I execute on a shell. If I execute this new script, it makes my program to run.

I added it as symbolic link to rc5 folder. I tried rebooting but nothing happens. Do I need to do anything else?

How can I get this to work with a recipe. In the end, I would want to have this automated.

Comment: Use the full path, not the relative path (e.g. /home/user/code/ProgramName as opposed to ProgramName)

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution for running a program at boot is to create a crontab entry for it like this:

```
@reboot /path/to/program
```

This is usually adequate for programs that are not system daemons.

The `@reboot` tag will ensure that the program is started when the system has booted and is supported on *most* cron implementations:

```
@reboot        Run once, at startup.          
@yearly        Run once a year, "0 0 1 1 *".  
@annually      (same as @yearly)              
@monthly       Run once a month, "0 0 1 * *". 
@weekly        Run once a week, "0 0 * * 0".  
@daily         Run once a day, "0 0 * * *".   
@midnight      (same as @daily)               
@hourly        Run once an hour, "0 * * * *".
```

For more info, see `man 5 crontab` on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this Q/A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/365559/insserv-script-is-broken/365579#365579) for similar discussion.
And add header in your script:

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Sample_GT02 daemon startup script
# Description:       Sample Server for GT02 class 
### END INIT INFO
```

Comment: Thanks. I added the header. I tried following the tutorial on that page but I get this answer: -sh: update-rc.d: command not found... as I said, I am running yocto. Maybe there are some packages I have no installed so I cannot run that command. Is it possible to do by hand? I mean, modifying some files when I create the image so I don't have to execute commands the first time.

Comment: Check where is your shell. Edit first line of the script

Comment: echo $0 returns -sh

Comment: Use absolute paths. And you can `source` the bash profile file from the user you use to run the program

Answer (score 0):

In your recipe add:

- INITSCRIPT_NAME and add filename of the initialization script that you need installed to etc/init.d.
- INITSCRIPT_PARAMS and specify the runlevel of your script, and the initlevels at which the script should run.

For example you can refer file in "poky/meta/recipes-connectivity/connman/connman.inc". You'll see following example usage.

```
    INITSCRIPT_NAME = "connman"
    INITSCRIPT_PARAMS = "start 05 5 2 3 . stop 22 0 1 6 ."
```

In the above snippet connman script ins being installed at ect/init.d and the script has a runlevel of 05, script starts in initlevels 2, 3 and 5, and stops  in levels 0, 1 and 6.